# how to change background-color of td elements based on other td elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I've the below html table having multiple **td** elements. I'm stuck with this problem now. If any one of the **td** elements are having background color as red, that complete row should be highlighted in red, it means other **td** elments in that row should be highlighted.

Below is the sample html.

```
<table border="1" class="CSSTableGenerator">

<style>
.foo {
    background-color: green;
}

.foo2 {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

<tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Properties</th>
    <th>J02</th>
    <th>W02</th>
</tr>

<td>OccoR1CutoverConfiguration</td>
    <td>reservationCutoverSwitch</td>
    <td class="trueValue foo">false</td>
    <td class="trueValue foo">false</td>
    <tr />
<tr />

<td>IntegrationConfiguration</td>
    <td>exactTargetAppKey</td>
    <td class="falseValue foo2">SGEwbW94OkMwH7g0f4tSN5MAC504gSSG</td>
    <td class="falseValue foo2">SGEwbW94OkMwH7g0f4tSN5MAC504gSSG</td>
    <tr />
<tr />
</table>
```

The above code highlights only **td** element holding **SGEwbW94OkMwH7g0f4tSN5MAC504gSSG** in red color. Is there a way we can highlight the complete row starting from **IntegrationConfiguration** to **SGEwbW94OkMwH7g0f4tSN5MAC504gSSG** using jquery?

Comment: can you give the tds above the last ones the class `foo2`?

Comment: What code have *you* tried?

Answer (score 2):

first you check your table there have same problam fixed those , Problam is some you did't start some tr But you end tr .
then try this it will Add class in this tr how have td with class foo

```
$('td').hasClass('foo').(this).closest('td').addClass('foo');
```

Comment: I think you meant foo2 :)

Comment: whatever which class you want you can use. :)

Answer (score 1):

The working code is the following fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/c8dh6vy8/
Here is the jquery code

```
$(function(){
$('td').each(function(){
if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') 
{
$('td',$(this).parent()).css({'background-color':'red'});
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Filter `tr` elements based on `hasClass` over `td` elements.

```js
$('tr').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('td').hasClass('foo2');
}).addClass('foo2')
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
.foo2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="CSSTableGenerator">
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Properties</th>
    <th>J02</th>
    <th>W02</th>
  </tr>

  <td>OccoR1CutoverConfiguration</td>
  <td>reservationCutoverSwitch</td>
  <td class="trueValue foo">false</td>
  <td class="trueValue foo">false</td>
  <tr />
  <tr />

  <td>IntegrationConfiguration</td>
  <td>exactTargetAppKey</td>
  <td class="falseValue foo2">SGEwbW94OkMwH7g0f4tSN5MAC504gSSG</td>
  <td class="falseValue foo2">SGEwbW94OkMwH7g0f4tSN5MAC504gSSG</td>
  <tr />
  <tr />
</table>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/kntv9qx1/)

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question like this:
If any `td` hasclass foo... AddClass foo

See [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/9dqxsh6t/).
Notice that I made corrections on your `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".foo").siblings().addClass("foo");
    $(".foo2").siblings().addClass("foo2");
});
```

**EDIT**

If it is a possible case to have a `trueValue` AND `falseValue` in the same row...
Do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".foo").siblings().addClass("foo");
    $(".foo2").siblings().addClass("foo2").removeClass("foo");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First find the elements with the `foo2` class, then navigate from those `<td>` elements to the ancestor `<tr>`:

```
$('td.foo2').closest('tr').addClass('foo2');
```

```js
$('td.foo2').closest('tr').addClass('foo2');
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
.foo2,
.foo2 td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="CSSTableGenerator">
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th>Properties</th>
    <th>J02</th>
    <th>W02</th>
  </tr>

  <td>OccoR1CutoverConfiguration</td>
  <td>reservationCutoverSwitch</td>
  <td class="trueValue foo">false</td>
  <td class="trueValue foo">false</td>
  <tr />
  <tr />

  <td>IntegrationConfiguration</td>
  <td>exactTargetAppKey</td>
  <td class="falseValue foo2">SGEwbW94OkMwH7g0f4tSN5MAC504gSSG</td>
  <td class="falseValue foo2">SGEwbW94OkMwH7g0f4tSN5MAC504gSSG</td>
  <tr />
  <tr />
</table>
```